# Unused E Visa for Indonesia

Tags: visas, indonesia, e-visas, bali

My husband and I are traveling to Indonesia in July 2024. I applied for the eVisa yesterday and received it. But I did not realize that I had applied too early: the visa expires in May, two months before we will even go to Indonesia. I have reached out to the visa office via email, but I thought I would ask here to see if anyone has any input. Will this ruin our chances of another e-visa closer to our arrival?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**, you'll be fine.

As a rule, unused visas are not a problem, they don't count "against" you on future applications.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had a feeling but just don't want to be caught off guard.

Comment: @SarahYoho Glad to help.  Please click the ✔️ mark if this answered your question!